# Copy row, paste to different sheet, then text to column, then transpose

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a small piece of code that will perform 3 different functions in one really.

In Sheet1 I have 4 columns of data, this is a variable amount of rows, with the 4th column containing data that will need to be delimited, as it contains a semicolon, this is also a variable amount of data.

I want to be able to copy these 4 columns to Sheet2, row-by-row ensuring I have delimited the 4th column, then transpose it removing all data from the 4th and replacing with the transposed data.

In addition to this I want it to be able to loop through so that all has been copied and transposed etc, so that there is a 1 row gap between the data on Sheet2, this gap will be from the end of the 4th column as its a variable amount of data.

If anyone can assist I would be very grateful.

Here is the code I am working with at the moment, it allows me to copy the first row of 4 columns, then paste onto Sheet2.

```
Sub Test1()
    Sheets("FT Raw").Select
    Range("A2").Select

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("FT WDs").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: It would help to include some sample before/after data. You should also include your existing code: if you don't have any, then try writing some and update your question with it.  Right now your question is just a set of requirements, with no indication of what you've tried and what problems you're having.

Comment: Here is some of the code I have put together so far.

   Sub Test1()

      Sheets("Raw").Select
      Range("A2").Select
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
      
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("WDs").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Loop
   End Sub

Comment: You can update your question to add code: code in comments is impossible to read.

Comment: If a source row contains multiple values in the forth column, how should that look after the transpose?  If Row 1 contains | data | data | data | a;b;c |, then when you copy it over, split and transpose the a,b,c values, they will extend downward into two other rows and presumably overwrite what they contain.  Unless that's what you mean by "gap": in the case of that first row transpose, there should be the copied row and then two blank rows so that the a,b,c don't conflict with the next set of data?

Comment: Yes, so ideally I would like to get the code take the row1 data from sheet1, then paste into sheet2. Then take a;b;c, split then transpose, move up one cell and delete the old split data.

Comment: Then repeat the whole process, but leaving a 1 row gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** updated to sort the array before transposing and adding the sheet.

Include QuickSort sub from http://en.allexperts.com/q/Visual-Basic-1048/string-manipulation.htm

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim shtSrc, shtDest, rngSrc, rwDest, r, arr, num

    Set rngSrc = Sheets("FT Raw").Range("A2")
    Set shtDest = Sheets("FT WDs")
    r = shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 2           
    Do While Len(rngSrc.Value) > 0
        shtDest.Rows(r).Cells(1).Resize(1, 3).Value = _
                     rngSrc.Resize(1, 3).Value
        arr = Split(rngSrc.Offset(0, 3).Value, ";")
        QuickSort arr, 0, UBound(arr) 'include method from link above...
        num = UBound(arr) + 1
        shtDest.Rows(r).Cells(4).Resize(num, 1).Value _
               = Application.Transpose(arr)
        r = r + num + 1

        Set rngSrc = rngSrc.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, that is fantastic!!!!! I really appreciate you help and guidance, you have saved me so much time. I will learn from this.

Comment: Tim, would it be difficult to add into the code a sort A-Z for the transposed data?

Comment: There's a sort method here http://en.allexperts.com/q/Visual-Basic-1048/string-manipulation.htm - if you call the sub with `QuickSort arr, 0, ubound(arr)` it should sort the array and then you can add it to the sheet.